# Ansible can't install Windows INF driver

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Ansible Version : 2.7.5
Target OS : Windows Server 2016 R2

The driver paackage files are located at `C:\imdisk_inst` folder.

If I run the following command in PowerShell manually, it works fine.

```
Start-Process -FilePath C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe -ArgumentList "setupapi.dll,InstallHinf
Section", "DefaultInstall", "132", "C:\\imdisk_inst\\imdisk.inf" -Verb RunAs -WorkingDirectory C:\imdisk_inst
```

**If the exact command run in Ansible playbook, there is no error but files are not installed.**

Here is part of playbook of this section

  `- name: Install In-Memory Disk Driver
    win_shell: 'Start-Process -FilePath C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe -ArgumentList "setupapi.dll,InstallHinfSection", "DefaultInstall", "132", "C:\\imdisk_inst\\imdisk.inf" -Verb RunAs -WorkingDirectory C:\imdisk_inst'`

And here is output of ansible:

```
TASK [Install In-Memory Disk Driver] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/jerry/UBS/doc/playbook/win.yml:20
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/windows/win_shell.ps1
<135.298.156.60> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: xxx on PORT 5986 TO 135.298.156.60
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
changed: [135.298.156.60] => {
    "changed": true, 
    "cmd": "Start-Process -FilePath C:\\Windows\\system32\\rundll32.exe -ArgumentList \"setupapi.dll,InstallHinfSection\", \"DefaultInstall\", \"132\", \"C:\\\\imdisk_inst\\\\imdisk.inf\" -Verb RunAs -WorkingDirectory C:\\imdisk_inst", 
    "delta": "0:00:00.671929", 
    "end": "2018-12-19 09:55:51.890787", 
    "rc": 0, 
    "start": "2018-12-19 09:55:51.218858", 
    "stderr": "", 
    "stderr_lines": [], 
    "stdout": "", 
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

Please where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not all commands can be run via remote powershell.  The primary reason for such errors is that several commands, and likely the ones that you are running, require elevated control (UAC) or a UI expecting a user response.  Such commands will not work when run through remote powershell (winrm, the underlying technology being used by ansible).